# iOS7 Keyboard Behavior with SearchBar/UITableView: Offset on secondary view appearances

Tags: ios7, keyboard, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uiresponder

**Problem**

I am having a rather big issue with the iOS7 keyboard appearance. I have a Searchbar on a UIViewController with TableView Delegation/Data Source setup (I am using the self.searchDisplayController delegates as well). I segue from this scene to a prototype tableview to show the results.

Here is the issue:

On first load I can see the keyboard being displayed when I tap into the text field of the UISearchBar. I can type and perform a search with the results being shown in the next scene.

I've added NSNotifications to view the keyboard properties in local methods keyboardWillShow and keyboardWasShown. I can see on the first scene appearance (after  the view is completely loaded):

[image: Keyboard Shown]

I segue to the result tableview at this point and when I navigate back and touch the text field, my keyboard shows up either fully or partially off-screen:

[image: Partial Keyboard]

When I look at the keyboardWillShow notification at this point I can see that my keyboard values are incorrect:

[image: Second round through]

I've researched and tried many possibilities including:

Added the following to my main view controller:

```
-(BOOL)canResignFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Configured the following in my view did load

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.spellCheckingType = UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType=  UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
```

Put in standard stubs for:

```
-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

I've noticed that if I choose a Partial Curl as my segue mode, the keyboard remains accessible when I roll back to the main view controller (but then it was never fully off screen in that case). However if I move from the results tableview to a detail scene and then navigate back to the main view controller, the keyboard appears off-screen again.

**Question**

Is there a method I can use to intercept the misplaced keyboard so that it displays in the default location?

NB: Along these lines, I have created a NSDictionary property to hold the initial userInfo values with the correct keyboard placement. I am not sure how to reassign these values to get the keyboard to return to it's original placement.

BTW - This seems a bit of a hack to get the keyboard fixed due to a bug in IB, is there some other way that I can try to remedy the situation?

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

This was such an obscure issue that I'm sharing the solution to save the next person some effort. Like most programming issues, it turns out this one was self-inflicted. In my original iteration of this project I had turned off rotational support as I am learning auto-layout and I wanted to ease into the transition from Springs and Struts. Somehow between the start of the project and the code release I ended up with this bit of code in the Main Scenes' View Controller.

```
//BAD
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations  
{
    return !UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

instead of returning a valid enumeration like...

```
//OK
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```